# Is the Auditory Spectrogram the same as the Magnitude Spectrogram?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, spectrogram

This is in the context of speech signals. The magnitude spectrogram is computed by framing the signal into short time windows, applying a hamming (or similar) window, computing the fft over each window, and taking the absolute value of the complex numbers obtained. I came across the Auditory Spectrogram in a paper and several toolkits (http://amtoolbox.sourceforge.net/amt-0.9.5/doc/general/audspecgram.php, http://www.isr.umd.edu/Labs/NSL/Software.htm). Do they refer to the same thing? Or else, how is the auditory spectrogram computed and what are the differences between the two representations?

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: As Jazzmaniac pointed out, the below answer I've given is incorrect. See Jazzmaniac's comment for explanation!**

The first source you provide contains this image as an example output of the function `audspecgram()`:

[image]

This very much appears to be a standard spectrogram of an acoustic signal. To describe it as an 'auditory spectrogram' might just hint to that fact—that it's derived from an acoustic signal. In other words: you are right in suspecting that what is described as an 'auditory spectrogram' in your source is just a spectrogram that is a result of exactly the procedure you describe to obtain it.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not correct. The term auditory spectrogram specifically refers to a spectrogram that is obtained from a model of at least the first layer of auditory perception. In most cases it is the magnitude spectrogram produced by an auditory filterbank.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I put in a disclaimer at the top.

Comment: That's just a filter-bank type spectrograph graphed by an array of filters, one at every frequency. I prefer these to FFT's although FFT is faster.